# Rails .each enumerator with a special case for the first line

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to put an enumerator to run over the top of a (refills/bourbon) front end framework. The element is a tab accordian which has repeatable elements but a special `is-active` class tag which flags to javascript which one should be expanded and the focus of a users attention.

I want to design an enumerator to create tabs and fill content based on how many records there are in ActiveRecord so I'm using an enumerator - but is there a smart way I can create a clean exception for the first `<a>` it outputs so it includes the `is-active` tag?

Currently my murky hack is below:

```
<div class="vertical-tabs-container">
  <div class="vertical-tabs">
    <% tab_num = 0 %>
    <% @user.items.each do |item| %>
    <% tab_num += 1 %>          
    <% if tab_num = 1 %> 
            <%= content_tag( :a, @user.item, :class=>"js-vertical-tab vertical-tab is-active, :rel="tab#{tab_num}", :href="javascript:void(0) %>  
          <% else %>
            <%= content_tag( :a, @user.item, :class=>"js-vertical-tab vertical-tab, :rel="tab#{tab_num}", :href="javascript:void(0) %>
          <% end %>
      </div>

    ... content goes here...
    </div>
```

There seems something deeply un-rails about that tab_num bit... and I sense a disturbance in the MVC force for putting this in my view... Plus this way I'd have to have another enumerator for the body element of the vertical-tabs-container...

Anyone got a better idea of how to do this neatly?

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag#130-Optional-classes

Have just seen this too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this looks like it belongs in a helper or a presenter/decorator.

The code itself could be simplified. Helper method:

In your view:

```
<div class="vertical-tabs-container">
  <div class="vertical-tabs">
     <%= user_tabs(@user) %>
  </div>

... content goes here...
</div>
```

Then in your helper:

```
def user_tabs(user)
  output = ""
  user.items.each_with_index do |item,i| 
    output << content_tag(:a, item, :class=>"js-vertical-tab vertical-tab #{i == 0 ? '' : 'is-active'", :rel="tab#{i}", :href="javascript:void(0) 
  end
  output
end
```

However if you're going to start adding content and tabs seperately, take a look at [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) and define methods for tab and body on the item element.

Comment: Really interesting, hadn't realized each_with_index existed. Great tip, many thanks.